# 1st digit before taking modulo(10**9 + 7)

Tags: python, math, multiplication

I am multiplying many large numbers and finally taking modulo of it. To optimise this I am using MOD at each step. But I also want the 1st digit of the final answer. Is there any way to know that even after using MOD?

Or is there any other efficient way to do huge multiplication many times, get the final answer and extract the 1st digit from it?

Order of elements is 10^9 and number of multiplications is about 10^5

Comment: Maybe multiply the same numbers as floats. Unless you encounter massive (or very unfortunate) rounding errors, the first digit should be correct.

Comment: @tobias_k If I multiply the numbers normally with (*) it takes very long time. If I will multiply them as floats then also the time taken would be same. To reduce time I used MOD but due to that I am losing the 1st digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take 10 based logarithms, sum them up and take the fractional part of the sum.

think about scientific notation of large numbers.

Comment: So silly of me to not get this without asking. By the way thank you very much. Brain acts mysteriously sometimes...